# Express 4 router and href

Tags: node.js, express

Using Express 4 and the "router" *middleware*

In app.js i have the following:

```
var subpage = require('./routes/subpage');
var app = express();
app.use('/subpage', subpage);
```

in subpage.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('subpage', {
       title: 'Subpage'
    });
});
```

and in subpage.jade:

```
block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
  a(href='/todo') Todo
```

Is there any way I can make the subpage.jade - href render with "subpage/todo" without changing actual href it self. I have lot of hrefs in my templates, and I do not want to change these for every time I use the "subpage" in a project!?

Comment: I think you would have to send a 301 redirect to the browser to redirect it to subpage/todo

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('subpage', {
  title: 'Subpage',
  path: 'subpage'
    });
});
```

and in subpage.jade:

```
block content
   h1= title
   p Welcome to #{title}
   a(href='/#{path}/todo') Todo
```